# Correctly nesting if statements in SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a function that is not behaving as expected. It appears to me that this is because my IF statements are not nesting as I expect:

```
CREATE FUNCTION primaryTheme (
    @StoryNumber NVARCHAR(10)
    ,@ProductType NVARCHAR(10)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return VARCHAR(15)
    DECLARE @count INT

    SELECT @count = COUNT(THM.NAME)
    FROM Theme THM
    LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
    LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber

IF (@count = 0)
    IF (@ProductType = 'Sprint')
        SELECT @return = 'New Development'
    ELSE
        SELECT @return = NULL
ELSE
    IF (@count = 1)
        IF (@ProductType = 'Sprint')
            SELECT @return = THM.NAME
            FROM Theme THM
            LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
            LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
            LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
            WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber

IF (
        @return != 'Adaptive'
        OR @return != 'Corrective'
        OR @return != 'Perfective'
        OR @return != 'Preventative'
        )
    SELECT @return = 'New Development'
ELSE
    SELECT @return = THM.NAME
    FROM Theme THM
    LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
    LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber

IF (
        @return != 'Adaptive'
        OR @return != 'Corrective'
        OR @return != 'Perfective'
        OR @return != 'Preventative'
        OR @return != 'New Development'
        )
    SELECT @return = NULL
ELSE
    IF (@count > 1)
        IF (@ProductType = 'Sprint')
            SELECT @return = THM.NAME
            FROM Theme THM
            LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
            LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
            LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
            WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber
                AND THM.NAME != 'New Development'
                AND (
                    THM.NAME = 'Adaptive'
                    OR THM.NAME = 'Corrective'
                    OR THM.NAME = 'Perfective'
                    OR THM.NAME = 'Preventative'
                    )

IF (@return IS NULL)
    SELECT @return = 'New Development'
ELSE
    SELECT @return = THM.NAME
    FROM Theme THM
    LEFT JOIN ProductTheme PDT ON THM.PK_Theme = PDT.ThemeId
    LEFT JOIN StoryProductTheme SPT ON PDT.PK_ProductTheme = SPT.ProductThemeId
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON SPT.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    WHERE STY.Number = @StoryNumber
        AND THM.NAME = 'New Development'
        AND (
            THM.NAME = 'Adaptive'
            OR THM.NAME = 'Corrective'
            OR THM.NAME = 'Perfective'
            OR THM.NAME = 'Preventative'
            )

IF (@return IS NULL)
    SELECT @return = 'New Development'

RETURN @return
END
```

These IF satements:

```
IF (
        @return != 'Adaptive'
        OR @return != 'Corrective'
        OR @return != 'Perfective'
        OR @return != 'Preventative'
        )
    SELECT @return = 'New Development'
```

are supposed to be within the other ones. How do I make sure that they work correctly?

Comment: Use `begin` and `end`.

Comment: I can't believe that all of these ifs could possibly be necessary. But right from the beginning the logic seems way off. How on earth is `@count` ever going to be 0 or 1?

Comment: Whoops, I missed a piece I'll add it

Comment: Is it not possible to use `CASE WHEN`s instead of all of those nested `IF`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server executes one statement following an `IF` if `BEGIN` and `END` are not used.  It is suggested to just always use `BEGIN` and `END` (I think the MCTS toolkits state this).

Here is the syntax:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 1 
BEGIN
    -- Do Some Things
    print 'Do some things'

    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 1 
    BEGIN
        -- Do Some Things
        print 'Do some more things'
    END
END
```

And [here is the BOL link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) for the documenetation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the verbose style of BEGIN IF / END IF would help (as a commenter already suggested).  Also, have you tried running it in the Management Studio debugger?  Otherwise, you can sprinkle PRINT statements through the sproc to see how far it is getting.